# How to exit surelock

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, kiosk-mode

I am using the [SureLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock) application on an SGS3, however I want to exit the app.

I do not have the password to unlock it and I do not want to uninstall the app.

Comment: Why do you want to exit it? Is it your S3? Why do you not know the password? You will have to uninstall.

Comment: Which will be hard without knowing the password, I guess...

Comment: @Izzy Not if ADB is enabled ;)

Comment: Yupp, in that case you are probably correct: `pm uninstall` whould do the trick I guess. But considering that apps is using device administrator (the permissions point that way), I'm not 100% sure either...

Comment: the only way to exit SureLock is through admin password

Comment: @Izzy Oh, you can't uninstall device admins

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the soultion with the help of my techie friend

connect the device throgh USB and run the command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.HOME
```

a window comes up. select **TouchWiz Home** and select **Always**
android home screen will come up. reset the device and there you go... surelock is gone.

Thanks to **Léa** for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lukas answer did not work for me.

This did:

```
adb shell am kill com.gears42.surelock
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN
```

First command kills surelock. Second ask you for home app.

Answer (score -2):

Boot into safe mode, then delete the apps.

Comment: How do you do this?